How is it possible to trace CPU interruptions of VirtualBox guest?
I am trying to study linux kernel activity. I got some traces via perf, ftrace and other means. However I want to trace all CPU interruptions as well as other hardware interruptions which drive the kernel from top. I tried to build VirtualBox to change the source to print some debug msg on interrupt, but it seems to be very long process. Does VirtualBox includes some built in debugger option to trace hardware interruptions or is there exist any other way? Thank you.
I am trying to check VirtualBox vboxmanage debugvm tool, but I haven't been successful so far.
